# Click between the lines

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have multiple  defined as:

```
<a href="col_c.php?id=1&field='A'" target="Frame3">item A</a>
```

and also I have a jquery script:

```
$(".item").click(function(){ itemclick(this); });
```

When a user positions the mouse between the  items where the link is not active the itemclick() is executed without the link redirect.

How I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't show everything. It seems those links are inside other tags with class "item". So of course, if someone clicks outside a link but inside of that parent there won't be a "href" available to the function. There are several options, one would be to just not do anything if the clicked object is not a link `<a ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

Give your links a class like:

```
<a class="link" href="col_c.php?id=1&field='A'" target="Frame3">item A</a>
```

and then use

```
$(".link").click(function(){ itemclick(this); });
```

I assume your .item is a div layer or a table row so it is also triggered around your link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute the function only on the links themselves, not the whole parent (I expect your links are the children of something called `.item`).

```
$(".item a").click(function(){ itemclick(this); });
```